# Trying to make 2 different forms with 2 different action

Tags: php, html, forms

I need little help i am making an upload page, so i have two different forms and two different action

1. form is ajax picture upload (profile picture of user) its working fine action is `action='ajaximage.php'`
2. form is simple user info details like Name,Bio, etc etc. its also working fine.. and its action is `action="add.php"`

**Doubt/Problem**
In my website input boxes are not arranged orderly because of the design.

```
<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='add.php'>
    <b>Tittle</b>
    <input type="text" name="name">
</form>

<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
    <input type="file" title="Choose Image" name="photoimg" id="photoimg">
</form>

<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='add.php'>
    <b>Description</b>
    <textarea name="description" rows="1" cols="1"></textarea>

    <button input="submit">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

**Ajax image uploader is working but in case of `add.php` it is working only for Description.
I cannot change the design so how can it be solved ?? Please Help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bwoebi is right about the submits but I'd be very surprised if your arrangement would work anyway. By my reckoning you have 3 forms. Just using the same name again wouldn't work. A single form needs to be distinct - unless you want to do a whole lot of javascript processing on submit. Have another look at fixing your layout to keep forms together.

Just saw your comments above. Why have separate forms with separate actions anyway? Why not have one form with one action that simply does both the file upload and adds the details (presumably to a database)?

You could also simply have different submit buttons on your form and add an onclick attribute to each setting the action for the form to be different:

```
<input type="submit" name="sub1" value="Upload Image" onclick="document.myform.action='ajaximage.php';">
<input type="submit" name="sub2" value="Add User" onclick="document.myform.action='add.php';">
```

This means the form action will be changed depending on which submit button is used .

Comment: Arthur can you please tell me then how big big websites manage to code like this ?? Ex-  Dribble or twitter or youtube facebook they have name,bio,address, and upload pictures ajax and other details and then Save Changes

Comment: How ? i can't both goes to different tables and i don't think mixing up is such a good idea ? :S

Comment: @user2615947 they just submit it to a single script and the script will call different functions for the different inputs?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you using Javascript, JQuery or such to manipulate inputs from anywhere on a page in response to a button click and produce a POST. I'm simply describing how to use html forms effectively with PHP. I may be misunderstanding your query but it looks like you only want one "save" event to upload a file and save some user details. There is no reason why that can't be done using a single form.

Comment: Your right about my query Mr Arthur..but Ugh!! I don't go well with ajax script...becuz both were working so well now i have to make it in javascript :| sir can you help me in arranging it ??

Comment: bwoebi - can you tell me how can i make script like that ??

Comment: For a crude solution keeping your separate scripts, you could try the method above.

Comment: Thank you Arthur i'm trying to make it in jquery

Comment: That's cool. kayladnis is not wrong either. It's a case of many ways to skin a cat. I still think you are best to let the inbuilt HTML form posting into PHP take the strain as your starting point and add AJAX, Javascript and/or jQuery only as necessary. But there are also merits in looking to your strengths in terms of what programming language you are most confident in.

Comment: Yes.. Arthur I knw as kayladnls said she is right in her way.. but i was preferring if there could be a possibility to make it in simple form

Answer (score 1):

You need one submit button for each form. A submit button will just submit the form it is in.

Comment: But how ? it will not look nice for user to click on two SAVE CHANGES bro

Comment: Bwoebi...After all Ajax uploader doesnot have a submit button.. just need to figure how can i place different input boxes which will work for 1 action = add.php

Comment: @user2615947 yes, but then you need to use ajax for all the forms, not just for the uploader...

Answer (score 0):

To upload images via ajax you do not need to submt a form, that is the whole point of doing it via ajax. You can upload the image, and then submit the form for the text inputs.

pseudocode:

```
<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='add.php'>
<input name="name"/>
<input name="profilePic" id="profilePic"/>
<input name="descrption"/>
</form>
```

You can then use javascript(I prefer jQuery) to upload your image via ajax, specifying #profilePic.

Also, you should look at: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: My both functions are working...I think you got me wrong i mean to say that i have ajax uploader for image (working) & simple form for user data input (working)..i am not able to place it in correct position but i think i have to change the simple form into jquery as other guys are saying

Comment: If you're submitting a form to upload an image, it's not ajax. Ajax is asynchronous. 

If you want to upload the image and submit the form data all in one fell swoop, as Arthur Nicoll said, you can do that with a single, mutlipart form.

Comment: kayladnls & Arthur Thanks a lot for your replys. Now every thing is working fine and clear **I CHANGED THE DESIGN** and added   `document.myform.action` as Arthur said it is solved now :) & you look amazing :P